# RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: recyclerview, fragment, androidx

Buenas tardes compañeros

Estoy tratando de cargar un RecyclerView en un Fragment, pero me dice que no tiene LayoutManager cuando se lo puse en el XML. Os pongo el codigo que igual se entiende mejor:

XML

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/swiperefreshlayout"
android:name="com.es.yesod.conocetuciudad.PlaceholderFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.listaEventos.ui.main.PlaceholderFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listPrueba"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/eventos_fragment"
    >

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Y el onCreateView es este:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eventos_list, container, false);

    Context context = view.getContext();
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.listPrueba);
    swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefreshlayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAzul));

    recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            }
        }
    });

    adapterEventos = new MyEventosRecyclerViewAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            eventosList
    );
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterEventos);

    return view;
}
```

Espero que se pueda entender bien, me dice en el log que no encuentra el layoutManager a pesar que lo tiene puesto por XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya di con la solución:

En el XML donde esta el RecyclerView, debe ir asi:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/swiperefreshlayout"
   android:name="com.es.yesod.conocetuciudad.PlaceholderFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".ui.listaEventos.ui.main.PlaceholderFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/listPrueba"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
tools:listitem="@layout/eventos_fragment"
>

 </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el XML, pon siempre el nombre completo de la clase (con el *package* incluido):

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo fallo...¿Tiene algo que ver si va dentro de algún otro XML por algún casual?